# sonarqube sonarscanner for java repos

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonarscanner

I am setting up sonarqube scans for different repos in my distributed systems application. Some of these repos are in javascript and python, while others are in Java Maven. I started off using the Maven plugin scan for the Java repos, but had to generalize with the sonarscanner for the javascript and python repos.
Is it possible for me to set up the Java Maven scans to use sonarscanner as well? I am having some trouble setting up this scan and most of the examples and documentation I can find points me back to just using the Maven sonarqube scan.

Comment: could you please be a bit more specific about what you have tried and what is not working?

Comment: The entire reason for the existence of the "sonar:sonar" plugin is to simplify running a SonarQube scan for a Maven project. It looks at the maven project configuration to set particular SonarQube properties. It's really best to use the best tool for the job.  Use the Maven plugin for Maven builds, and use the sonar-scanner for everything else.